# Twig replace plus and two spaces in string

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a string like this:

```
Some + Name
```

I want that changed to

```
some-name
```

I'm using the replace filter which works nicely. However I need to replace a whole lot more characters (for use in urls) which conflict with the above string.

```
{{ product.brand.title | replace({' ' : '-', '/&' : '-', "'" : "", '+':'', '.':''}) | lower | raw }}
```

When using the above replace function with the mentioned string I get

```
Some--Name
```

What would be the best way to accomplish the desired string?? With in mind I need to change most characters into dashes. I tried `escape` as well but that didn't work properly. Think of:

```
Dr. Brown's -> dr-browns
Burt's Bees -> burts-bees
naïf care -> naif-care
```

Comment: You can always write an extension of your own, and do all the logic necessary in there and simply return the desired result. There is a chapter about this subject in the CookBook - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom Twig extension like that :

1- The Twig extension class :

```
class SlugifyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('slugify', array($this, 'slugifyFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function slugifyFilter($string)
    {
      $string = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $string);
      $string = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $string);
      $string = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $string);
      $string = trim($string, '-');
      $string = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $string);
      $string = strtolower($string);

      if (empty($string)) {
        return 'n-a';
      }

      return $string;

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'slugify_extension';
    }
}
```

2- register your Twig extension :

```
services:
    app.slugify_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

3- Then use it :

```
{{ product.brand.title|slugify }}
```

[More infos here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)